# Asp.Net WebApi Write Stream

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, streaming

I have the following scenario:

I want to make, in `Asp.Net WebApi`, an endpoint, which acts as a "stream".
The endpoint receives text, and appends it to a file on the disk.

The client, can connect to that endpoint, and "upload" custom text to the stream.

Basically, on the client, i want to create an HttpModule, which will connect to the endpoint on `BeginRequest` event, and will close the connection on `EndRequest` event.

Is this possible using Asp.Net WebApi?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean? Are you saying the client will make a request to this endpoint and upload text? It gets appended to the file...then next time they make a request you append that text to the file as well? That seems fairly straightforward, not sure where HTTPModules and BeginRequest come into any of that. Or are you trying to talk about a constant open connection where a stream of data arrives over time? For that kind of thing you probably need a WebSockets / SignalR implementation.

Comment: Why not let the client upload the whole file using a `HttpClient` with `PostStreamAsync` or create a controller method that the client calls multiple times to append a string parameter to the file. Not sure or it's possible to keep a request living like that. another possibility would maybe be to use a websocket and lay a connection with that.

Comment: Yes, i am talking "about a constant open connection where a stream of data arrives over time".

I want to avoid opening and closing a connection  for every chunk of text i want to send.

Comment: In that case I would research WebSockets / SignalR. It's not really possible using conventional HTTP.

Comment: @Dragonvil I would guess because there is no "file", and/or the content is not all known at the start. An obvious scenario would be an IM/chat app.

Comment: Fair enough, in that case I don't think the standard Http will support it and that he'll have to research something else like websockets/SignalR

Comment: @ADyson Thanks, i will try with SignalR. You can post this as an aswer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to allow for a constant open connection where a stream of data arrives in separate chunks over a period of time, then I would suggest that you research WebSockets / SignalR, which will provide this kind of functionality over the web.

It's not really possible to do what you're suggesting using conventional HTTP.